# Filter and display using id from object if matching criteria

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects from a database and I'm looking to filter the results if they match the correct criteria. (i.e if a user's id matches the correct id of the page then display the results for that user).

TS -

```
  async getResultsForId() {
    const resultsFromDB = await this.backendService.getResults();
    const serviceUserId = resultsFromDB.serviceUserId;
    if (serviceUserId === '1234567890') {
      resultsFromDB.filter(item => {
        return item.serviceUserId;
      });
    }
```

HTML -

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Reason" prop="reason" [minWidth]="100">
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
         <div class="row">
           <span> {{row.reasonType}} </span>
         </div>
          <div class="row" *ngIf="row.reasonDescription !== 'None'">
            <span class="instructions"> {{row.reasonDescription}} </span>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
 </ngx-datatable-column>
```

[image: I have logged the results, but for example in this case I only want to display results that have the serviceUserId of '1234567890']

I have logged the results, but for example in this case I only want to display results that have the serviceUserId of '1234567890'

Comment: You are using TS - just start using type annotations and you'll start to uncover the errors. Then use a debugger to check your execution. By eyeballing your function, I counted 3 issues:  1. ignoring the result of `filter` 2. not using any comparison in filtering predicate 3. Compete mess in field access. If `resultsFromDB` is an object, it does not have `filter`, if it is an array, it does not have `serviceUserId` (shouldnt you take that as a parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the `.filter` method and check if the values of your `serviceUserId` matches your string. So for example:

```
async getResultsForId() {
    const resultsFromDB = await this.backendService.getResults();
    const serviceUserId = resultsFromDB.serviceUserId;
    const filterdResult = this.resultsFromDB.filter(result: any => result.serviceUserId === serviceUserId);
    return filterdResult;
}
```